# What happens in the Debian community around 2010?

Tags: debian

I was looking at the [statistics of the Debian project on BlackDuck OpenHub](https://www.openhub.net/p/debian). I notice a significative decrease of the number of contributors and of the number of commits around 2010. How to explain this? Is it a problem in the statistics or something really happened?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Interesting question, but perhaps limit-off-topic.... More a history question than a software one....

Comment: Strong community produces reliable software, it's maybe an historical question but it implies the quality of the debian distribution now.

Comment: That could be an explanation.

Comment: Also OpenHub doesn't track all of Debian...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about Unix or Linux within the scope defined in the help center.  It's more a history question than a software one.